# ESXi 7.0.3 unable to start VM after a cancelled export

Tags: vmware-esxi

I cancelled the export of a VM via ovftool when I realised the partition it was being dumped to wasn't going to be big enough.
As a direct result of this, the VM cannot be powered on, with the surprising error

`Failed - The attempted operation cannot be performed in the current state (Powered off).`

Googling this error gives me nothing, the closest matches on the VMware KB refer to "Powered on", which makes sense, you can't power on a VM that is already powered on. But in this case it's telling me I can't power on a VM because it is currently powered off, and for the life of me I can't fix this.  I can't unregister it either, that gives the same error above.

Can this be fixed without a reboot?  The machine is running as a standalone VM host.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after to cancel an OVA export, I fixed it restarting 2 services, hostd and vpxa on vmware host:

```
/etc/init.d/hostd restart

/etc/init.d/vpxa restart
```

After that I could remove vm with problem.